# How to fix below-cloudfront distribution update error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cli

I was trying to update **cloudfront** distribution`(disable/remove OriginSSLprotocol:SSLv3)` using below commands

1. `aws cloudfront get-distribution-config --id E29BDBENPXM1VE | jq  'del(.DistributionConfig.Origins.Items[].CustomOriginConfig.OriginSslProtocols.Items[0])|.DistributionConfig.Origins.Items[].CustomOriginConfig.OriginSslProtocols.Quantity=3'>test.json`
2. `aws cloudfront update-distribution --id E29BDBENPXM1VE --distribution-config (cat test.json |jq -r .DistributionConfig)  --if-match (cat test.json | jq -r .ETag)`

Command 2 resulted in below error:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Can anyone please help me out on above issue ,also wanted to know how to merge above 2 commands to make as single line command

Comment: can anyone please help me out on this

Comment: can anyone please help me out on this

Comment: did you find a solution to your problem?